# MVC giving 404 errors after VS2010 install and VS2008 rollback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, model-view-controller, iis, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a bit of a problem with an MVC 1.0 site and wondered if anyone could help. The site was fully working in Visual Studio 2008, but after an upgrade to VS2010 I am having problems.

The steps I have taken so far are:

Install VS2010

Upgrade my MVC site to .net 4.0/MVC 2.0, which generally worked

Shelved all my changes

Got latest (to get the previous VS2008 version) in VS2008

Found I got a HTTP 500.19 error when running the site, which I resolved as per this blog post http://andrew-murphy.co.uk/?p=129

Now for some reason I am getting a HTTP 404, its like the routing isn't working as expected, even though it was all previously working. If anyone has seen this or has any idea then I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I should have stressed that the version I have now, which is getting the 404 error is the original MVC 1.0 code base, with no changes at all. I'm thinking the issue is probably IIS related, if I find anything I'll post it up.

Comment: Check your asp.net version for your site. Is it still running on the .net 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

You were not supposed to "upgrade" you project from MVC1 to MVC 2. You need to create a new MVC2 project and copy out your old source files into your new project.